# Enumerate environment begin at 3 not 1

Tags: environments

I want to begin 3 (not 1) in enumerate environment

My Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Three
    \item Four
    \item Five
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[start=3]
    \item Three
    \item Four
    \item Five
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]